# Error: Could not find or load main class IntelliJIdea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, classpath

I am trying to run a JavaFX application on intellij but no matter what I try I can't get it to work and have been trying for hours. I am at this stage now where I am getting this error whenever I try to run.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class C:\Desktop\javafx-sdk-11.0.-3.2\lib
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: C:\Desktop\javafx-sdk-11.0.-3.2\lib
```

[Intellij Run Configuration Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cS3CG.png)

Passing VM Options: `--add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml`

JRE is project default.

Working directory is: `/Users/julienhuff/IdeaProjects/Hangman`

Comment: Remove the path to JavaFX from the VM Options field. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2019.3/javafx.html for the updated documentation. See also https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/.

Comment: What `java`-version are you using? if you're unsure open commandline and enter `java -version` as javaFX was removed from the jdk in java11

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gradle or maven you can try this:

build.gradle:

```
application {
  mainClassName = 'path to your main class including packages'}
```

pom.xml:

```
<configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>path to your main class including packages</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
</configuration>
```